# How to resolve "Renamed in both source and destination"

Tags: git, bitbucket, rename, conflict

I have a conflicted file on BitBucket pull request. It says `Renamed in both source and destination`. How am I supposed to resolve the conflict? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is the same file and the content hasn't been modified:

- If you want to keep only one of the 2 paths for the file, run `git add the-path-i-want-to-keep; git rm the-path-i-don-not-want`
- If you want to to move it to a separate path, take one of them, move it and delete the other: `git mv one-path path-i-do-want; git rm another-path`

Then you can move on with the operation.